# Is "http://" or "mailto:" considered as a namespace in semantic languages such as RDF?

Tags: namespaces, rdf, xml-namespaces

Is it correct to say that `http://` or `mailto:` are a namespace in RDF?

Where can I find a definition what a namespace is? An can I say that a namspace is a URI?

Comment: Well no, it's (http, mailto,ftp, ...) indeed just the *protocol*, look at the definition of URI/URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDF itself has no notion of namespaces. However several RDF serialization formats (like RDF/XML and Turtle) use namespaces to abbreviate URIs such as by using [CURIEs](https://www.w3.org/TR/curie/). The CURIE spec mandates the prefix to be mapped to an IRI, so you couldn't map it to just "http://".

Comment: *"RDF itself has no notion of namespaces"* -- well... [The IRIs in an RDF vocabulary often begin with a common substring known as a ***namespace IRI***.](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#vocabularies) *"The term **“namespace”** on its own does not have a well-defined meaning in the context of RDF,"* though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself. Here is the answer:

A uri consists of the following format:

```
URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
```

A URI must contain a scheme and a path. http and mailto are only schemes and not considered as a URI because the path is missing.

A namespace is definied by a uri. However, http:// and mailto: is not a URI and that is why they are not a namespace.